# Color mismatch between render and viewport

Tags: color, color-management

Initially, the colors were greyish in the viewport aswell - after changing the color management settings in the render tab, the viewport is as it should be - but when I render it out, it remains with wrong colors. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Edit: The slight tint of the image in general is due to f.lux. But the issue remains even if turned off.

Edit 2:

I already found out about color management settings that are set to filmic by default in 2.8+. In this specific case I've set it to raw as the texture input I'm rendering is in raw format, but for the albedo textures, I used standard, which still tints the render - not the viewport. The viewport was greyish before when the setting was on 'filmic' too. But changing the color management settings fixed that - but not the render.

This is what I'm trying to understand here, as the color management settings are part of the render tab, and I don't understand why the render tab changes my viewport, but not the render.

I found a quick fix by using "render viewport" instead of the normal render. But it's still awkward to not know what's going on.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender image output is greyish and not white](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176754/blender-image-output-is-greyish-and-not-white) and [Why rendering gets a faded color](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151380/why-rendering-gets-a-faded-color-video/176782#176782)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I already googled and read about this. As I wrote in the initial question, I already changed the color management settings - in this case not to standard but raw, as the texture map input is raw/non-color. For others I'd choose standard, and it removes the greyish tint from the viewport - but not from the render.
I found a quickfix by using render viewport instead of the normal render. But I'd still like to know what makes the VP differ from the render. The color management settings are part of the render tab after all, and so far they fixed the VP for me, not the render.

Comment: Film is set to transparent. Though, this is not visible in the viewport image. So this image is not a rendered view. Can you confirm?

Comment: It's the diffuse color pass of the render, i.e no transparency